# Disable 'Windows Security' Dialog

Tags: windows, windows-xp, security, regedit, dialog

In Windows XP can I disable the 'Windows 'Security Dialog box using regedit?
Heres what it looks like:

[image]

Regards, Snipe

Comment: No; you cannot.

Comment: `1.` What do you mean `disable it`? `2.` Why would you want to?

Comment: Never Mind, I found a way: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
AllowMultipleTSSessions = 1 (DWORD)
Or LogonType = 0 (DWORD)
or HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\explorer
NoWelcomeScreen = 0 (DWORD)